# Arraylist is empty after JavaRDD<String>.foreach in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-7, anonymous-function

Sample json (*total 100 records*):

> {"name":"dev","salary":10000,"occupation":"engg","address":"noida"}
>   {"name":"karthik","salary":20000,"occupation":"engg","address":"noida"}

Useful code:

```
   final List<Map<String,String>> jsonData = new ArrayList<>();

   DataFrame df =  sqlContext.read().json("file:///home/dev/data-json/emp.json");
   JavaRDD<String> rdd = df.repartition(1).toJSON().toJavaRDD(); 

   rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
       @Override
       public void call(String line)  {
           try {
               jsonData.add (new ObjectMapper().readValue(line, Map.class));
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
               System.out.println("List size: "+jsonData.size());
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });

   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   System.out.println("List size: "+jsonData.size());
```

`jsonData` is empty in the end.

Output:

```
Executor task launch worker-1
List size: 1
Executor task launch worker-1
List size: 2
Executor task launch worker-1
List size: 3
.
.
.
Executor task launch worker-1
List size: 100

main
List size: 0
```

Comment: Since the list seems to be empty at the start, could it be the object mapper can't parse the lines it gets? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What is `rdd` ?

Comment: Maybe the `System.out.println` is execute before the foreach has completed its task (or as even started)?

Comment: ObjectMapper is parsing properly. It is adding in the list in each iteration

Comment: @khelwood  rdd is JavaRDD<String>. I modified question

Comment: @freedev I tried without `System.out.println`. It's still empty

Comment: What did the println show? Can you show some lines?

Comment: Do the `System.out.println()` invocations inside the function print anything?  Else it seems likely that no data are being processed.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a `JavaRDD<String>` into a `List<Map<String,String>>`? if yes this is not the right way.

Comment: @freedev yes I am trying to do the same.

Comment: That *final* keyword has nothing to do with the list being empty after being processed. It just tells the compiler that this variable/field should not be initialized again. If your list is empty, then because **no** add calls take place.

Comment: I am  a beginner in Spark. This is done because a different partition is updating it's value. It's more of a spark related question. Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with you. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Is each line you are mapping out as Map form a set of Key, Value pairs?

Comment: Why are you using `filterDf` instead of `df`?

Comment: @alayor sry man. It's typo. I tried to simplify code

Comment: Step through this with a debugger. I bet the answer leaps out.

Comment: Show us the output you're getting. I could help to figure out.

Comment: @alayor check my updated question

Comment: @devツ could you give me the version of spark libraries you are using?

Comment: @slim On debugging I found `call` function is called in different thread by spark executer.

Comment: @freedev  `call` function is called in different thread by spark executer. Hence, after returning to main thread list is empty.  spark version 1.6.2

Comment: @devツ I knew when I wrote that the `System.out.println` is executed before your task is started... :) I have just to see how to call `map` in java 7.

Comment: @freedev added some more info in the question

Comment: @devツ I've updated my answer, have a look please

Comment: I guess it's a closure-related issue. See this part of spark's guide for more details: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and this works
https://github.com/freedev/spark-test

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Map<String, Object>> list = rdd
        .map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<String, Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> call(String line) throws Exception {
                TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                };
                Map<String, Object> rs = objectMapper.readValue(line, typeRef);
                return rs;
            }
        }).collect();
```

I preferred mapping `Map<String, Object>` because this will handle cases not where in your Json the value part is not a string (i.e. `"salary":20000`).

Comment: The question is tagged `java-7`. Java 8 code is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @freedev thanks for the effort. I tried it, but getting `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)` even after adding `implements Serializable` to the main class from which I am running main method

Comment: I have just tried this code here https://github.com/freedev/spark-test and works like a charm.

Comment: creating `typeRef` outside anonymous function is creating problem. It worked after changing. Thanks for the help.